# PKIX path building failed :SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target: MICROSOFT azure function URL

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

We have a azure function app deployed, In our java project, we get the data using the azure function URL.
While sending a GET request, it is failing with the following exception

`REST Api call 'https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/api/xxx?code=xxx' failed with response body - I/O error on GET request for "https://xxx-fa.azurewebsites.net/api/xxx": PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`